# pip is apparently installed but not working

Tags: 16.04, python, pip

As background, I am trying to back out of my anaconda distro and use pip to do my own package management. I had an old anaconda version 3.4 which I have deleted. I upgraded python to 3.5 alongside Ubuntu 16.04 and am in the process of re-installing all the rest of the packages that I use.

Here is my problem with pip, in a nutshell.

```
:~/Downloads$ python --version
Python 3.5.2
:~/Downloads$ python get-pip.py
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
:~/Downloads$ pip install -U pip
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python3-pip
:~/Downloads$ pip install scipy
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Now, the apt install pip does in fact work. But then I have myriad problems with that version of pip that I have not experienced before, foremost among which is the fact that I can't install the apt managed pip to 9.0.1 from 8.1.1. So I apt removed pip and am now back to square one.

But all that is irrelevant, I want to get pip working as is. What is going wrong with get-pip.py?

Answer (score 7):

Installing pip with apt should not be the answer.

You installed PIP right, but you have to add the executable path to you PATH variable,

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

You can add this to the end of `~/.profile` to make the change permanent. You may need to run `source ~/.profile` in a new shell, or you can log out and back in.

Comment: To note is that new user accounts from Ubuntu 16.04 onwards would already have `$HOME/.local/bin` in `PATH`. See the last line of `.profile` in https://gist.github.com/edwinksl/dafc0594176df6058bb395e985833189#file-profile.

Answer (score 0):

you verify that python is installed, but you don't check if pip is. you can check it with.

```
$ pip --version
pip 8.1.1 from /Users/aidanmelen/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

You can install pip with apt as suggested to you with

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Remember, **Python** is the interpreter. It will interpret your python programs and **pip** stands for Pip Installs Python or PIP Installs Packages. This helps you download, install, and manage python packages (3rd party libraries) such as scipy.

Comment: pip is not installed. 'which pip' gives nothing, and 'pip --version' gives the same error message as seen with any other pip command. My question is why get-pip.py thinks that it has successfully installed pip yet I can't find run it.

Comment: did you try <sudo apt install python3-pip>?

Comment: I did, and I do not want to install it that way. If the pip install page says that the preferred way is to install it by running their installer, than that is what I should do. If I can't do that, something is wrong.

Comment: i wouldn't install pip with get-pip.py when you could use apt.